# Merge two arrays in a sequential and structured way

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two separate and sequential arrays, my need is to combine the two arrays into one but with the sequential values, and obviously dynamic.

Let me explain better, these are the arrays I have:

```
var lat = [[45.4668729,44.8013268,45.4384958]];
var lng = [[9.1907501,10.3278351,10.9924122]];
```

What I need is this:

```
FinalARRAY = [[45.4668729,9.1907501],[44.8013268,10.3278351],[45.4384958,10.9924122]];
```

I took a test by writing like this:

```
var finalArray = new Array(3);
for (var i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
finalArray[i] = new Array(lat[0],lng[0]); 
}
```

Obviously it is not dynamic and only draws the first two values ​​for each lat and lng, this is because I put "lat [0]" but how can I value the array in a sequential and dynamic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me know if something is unclear in this solution, should be self explanatory.

It uses index of first array in loop to fetch item from 2nd array and push to new array.

```js
//FinalARRAY = [[45.4668729,9.1907501],[44.8013268,10.3278351],[45.4384958,10.9924122]];

var lat = [
  [45.4668729, 44.8013268, 45.4384958]
];
var lng = [
  [9.1907501, 10.3278351, 10.9924122]
];

var finalArray = []

lat[0].forEach((i, index)=>{
  finalArray.push([i,lng[0][index]])
})


console.log(finalArray)
```

This is not depended on number of arrays as long as lengths match:

```js
var lat = [
  [45.4668729, 44.8013268, 45.4384958],
  [1.1, 1.2, 1.3]
];
var lng = [
  [9.1907501, 10.3278351, 10.9924122],
  [2.1, 2.2, 2.3]
];

var finalArray = []

lat.forEach((e1, index) => {
  e1.forEach((e2, index2) => {
    finalArray.push([e2, lng[index][index2]])
  })
})

console.log(finalArray)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%
}
```

If you want add more vars:

```js
var lat = [
  [45.4668729, 44.8013268, 45.4384958],
];
var lng = [
  [9.1907501, 10.3278351, 10.9924122],
];

var nerArr = ["A","B","C"]


var finalArray = []

lat[0].forEach((i, index)=>{
  finalArray.push([i, lng[0][index], nerArr[index] ])
})

console.log(finalArray)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%
}
```

You push it with: `finalArray.push([i, lng[0][index], nerArr[index] ])`

where inside push you create outcome per one array item:

```
[i, lng[0][index], nerArr[index] ]
```

As seen I just appended `nerArr[index]` with specified index item.
You can easily add more:

```
[i, lng[0][index], nerArr[index], newArr2[index] ]
```

Comment: This code worked for me, thank you. But how can I add an third o fourth array in finalArray? Thank You

Comment: @AlessandroFerrigno I added new snippet into anwser.

Comment: Sorry @ikiK it was my mistake, I explained myself badly. 
I mean another array like var, besides lat and lng.

Let me explain better, if in addition to the 2 two array variables lat and lng I had a third variable constructed like this:

     var3 = ["A", "B", "C"];

So that then FinalArray becomes like this:

FinalARRAY = [
[45.4668729,9.1907501, "A"], 
[44.8013268,10.3278351, "B"],
 [45.4384958,10.9924122, "C"]
];

Comment: Woah It works! Really thank you, you've been really helpful